# Fancybox jquery conflict?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, conflicting-libraries

I am making a website that is building off of a template I found online. I wanted to add a gallery, so I  inserted the Fancybox2 code. I have double checked everything, and it appears I have pathed it all out properly. When I click on the image however... it doesn't show up in the light box.. it takes me to another page with just the image.

Is there a conflict somewhere in the header that I am not seeing that is causing this? Help anyone! Thank you!!

Also, I am sorry I can't get the code to read as one. I am sorry it is splitting in this view.

```
 <!-- Bootstrap Core CSS -->
 <link href="css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">

 <!-- Custom CSS -->
 <link href="css/grayscale.css" rel="stylesheet">

 <!-- Custom Fonts -->
 <link href="font-awesome/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
 <link href="http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lora:400,700,400italic,700italic" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
 <link href="http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Montserrat:400,700" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">

 <!-- HTML5 Shim and Respond.js IE8 support of HTML5 elements and media queries -->
 <!-- WARNING: Respond.js doesn't work if you view the page via file:// -->
 <!--[if lt IE 9]>
    <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/libs/html5shiv/3.7.0/html5shiv.js"></script>
    <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/libs/respond.js/1.4.2/respond.min.js"></script>
 <![endif]-->
 <link href="css/jquery.galereya.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
 <!--[if lt IE 9]>
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/jquery.galereya.ie.css">
 <![endif]-->
 <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7/jquery.min.js">            </script>
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="/fancybox/jquery.fancybox.css" type="text/css" media="screen" />
  <script type="text/javascript"src="/fancybox/jquery.fancybox.pack.js">
  $(document).ready(function() {
        /*
         *  Simple image gallery. Uses default settings
         */

        $('.fancybox').fancybox();

        /*
         *  Different effects
         */

        // Change title type, overlay closing speed
        $(".fancybox-effects-a").fancybox({
            helpers: {
                title : {
                    type : 'outside'
                },
                overlay : {
                    speedOut : 0
                }
            }
        });

        // Disable opening and closing animations, change title type
        $(".fancybox-effects-b").fancybox({
            openEffect  : 'none',
            closeEffect : 'none',

            helpers : {
                title : {
                    type : 'over'
                }
            }
        });

        // Set custom style, close if clicked, change title type and overlay color
        $(".fancybox-effects-c").fancybox({
            wrapCSS    : 'fancybox-custom',
            closeClick : true,

            openEffect : 'none',

            helpers : {
                title : {
                    type : 'inside'
                },
                overlay : {
                    css : {
                        'background' : 'rgba(238,238,238,0.85)'
                    }
                }
            }
        });

        // Remove padding, set opening and closing animations, close if clicked and disable overlay
        $(".fancybox-effects-d").fancybox({
            padding: 0,

            openEffect : 'elastic',
            openSpeed  : 150,

            closeEffect : 'elastic',
            closeSpeed  : 150,

            closeClick : true,

            helpers : {
                overlay : null
            }
        });

        /*
         *  Button helper. Disable animations, hide close button, change title type and content
         */

        $('.fancybox-buttons').fancybox({
            openEffect  : 'none',
            closeEffect : 'none',

            prevEffect : 'none',
            nextEffect : 'none',

            closeBtn  : false,

            helpers : {
                title : {
                    type : 'inside'
                },
                buttons : {}
            },

            afterLoad : function() {
                this.title = 'Image ' + (this.index + 1) + ' of ' + this.group.length + (this.title ? ' - ' + this.title : '');
            }
        });


        /*
         *  Thumbnail helper. Disable animations, hide close button, arrows and slide to next gallery item if clicked
         */

        $('.fancybox-thumbs').fancybox({
            prevEffect : 'none',
            nextEffect : 'none',

            closeBtn  : false,
            arrows    : false,
            nextClick : true,

            helpers : {
                thumbs : {
                    width  : 50,
                    height : 50
                }
            }
        });

        /*
         *  Media helper. Group items, disable animations, hide arrows, enable media and button helpers.
        */
        $('.fancybox-media')
            .attr('rel', 'media-gallery')
            .fancybox({
                openEffect : 'none',
                closeEffect : 'none',
                prevEffect : 'none',
                nextEffect : 'none',

                arrows : false,
                helpers : {
                    media : {},
                    buttons : {}
                }
            });

        /*
         *  Open manually
         */

        $("#fancybox-manual-a").click(function() {
            $.fancybox.open('1_b.jpg');
        });

        $("#fancybox-manual-b").click(function() {
            $.fancybox.open({
                href : 'iframe.html',
                type : 'iframe',
                padding : 5
            });
        });

        $("#fancybox-manual-c").click(function() {
            $.fancybox.open([
                {
                    href : '1_b.jpg',
                    title : 'My title'
                }, {
                    href : '2_b.jpg',
                    title : '2nd title'
                }, {
                    href : '3_b.jpg'
                }
            ], {
                helpers : {
                    thumbs : {
                        width: 75,
                        height: 50
                    }
                }
            });
        });


    });


    </script>

 </head>

 <body id="page-top" data-spy="scroll" data-target=".navbar-fixed-top">
 <!-- Look Section -->
 <section id="download" class="content-section text-center">
    <div class="download-section">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="col-lg-8 col-lg-offset-2">
                <h2>Look</h2>
                <p>You can download Grayscale for free on the preview page at Start Bootstrap.</p>
           <div id="gallery">
  <a class="fancybox" href="img/graphics/biomed-web.jpg" data-fancybox-group="gallery" title="Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet"><img src="img/graphics/biomed-web.jpg" alt=""></a>
 <a href="img/graphics/biomed-web.jpg" class="fancybox"><img src="img/graphics/biomed-web.jpg" height="230px" alt="" /></a>
 <a href="img/graphics/bookcg-web.jpg" class="fancybox"><img src="img/graphics/bookcg-web.jpg" height="230px" alt="" /></a>

            </div>
            </div>
        </div>
       </div>
    </section>
```

Comment: Please add your HTML. The only thing you have included is your HEAD section.

Comment: Does the debugger add any errors?

Comment: @magreenberg I added the HTML for the lightbox section. Do you see anything?

Comment: @asturnick, what is the debugger? where is that? I am learning :(

Comment: @ Axel Author Thank you for making corrections ,but I am still having the same issue.

Comment: The developer tool from the browser, a really cool tool you can use to see if any errors are occurring on your page. I do believe that the problem in your case (it is a guess though) that the path to your files aren't correct:
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="/fancybox/jquery.fancybox.css" type="text/css" media="screen" />
  <script type="text/javascript"src="/fancybox/jquery.fancybox.pack.js">
at least comparing them to the other paths you have for your files. Just check the dev tools to see if you have any 404 messages or other.

Comment: check out devtools for chrome: https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/?hl=en or
for firefox:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Tools or
for safari
https://developer.apple.com/safari/tools/ or
for internet explorer
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg589507(v=vs.85).aspx